# Is recovering from the recycle bin/rubbish bin/trash can available with Gnome or not?

Tags: trash

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and also downloaded Gnome desktop.

Is recovering from the recycle bin/rubbish bin/trash can available with Gnome or not?

I get conflicting answers about this from Forum search and “Answers”

Some say you can find it in “local” but I can find no local file where it should be.

One post says navigate to ~/.local/share/Trash/ but I cannot find “local”.

The only way I can find anything like this is Places>Computer>File System>usr>local>share but “share” contains no trash folder.

Is “~” the same as user name?

I am the only user on this pc, is that why I can't find it?

Others say you have to download Gnome Tweaks.
What I am looking for is the same in Gnome as there is in Unity, a trash can that you can open and restore trashed items from, but I don't seem to have it in Gnome, however if it is there somewhere I would rather find it than download Gnome Tweaks.

Also what is the correct term? Recycle bin, rubbish bin or trashcan? On my Ubuntu 12.04 when deleting it is referred to as “the rubbish bin” but no-one else seems to call it that, is it because I opted for English Language UK rather than US?

Answer (score 1):

The location you gave is correct  `~/.local/share/Trash` but the file you are looking for is hidden as signified by the `.`  Any file names that have a `.` preceding are hidden unless you force them to be shown.

Showing hidden files in Nautilus is done by pressing `Ctrl+H`

The `~` in the path signifies that the file is in the current users home directory it is short hand for `/home/{your username}/.local/share/Trash`

So to get to the trash files the way you were trying to do it it would be  Places>Computer>File System>home>{your username}   (then press `Ctrl+H`) >.local>share>Trash>files.

However it is easier to Places>Home(press `Ctrl+H`)>.local>share>Trash>files.

Both of the above are still doing it the hard way.  You can open the Trash(correct name BTW) directly and then right click and select `Restore` and it will go back to the folder it was deleted from.  Alternatively, you can drag and drop it to any place you want as well.  If I remember correctly(could be wrong I use Unity) the Trash icon is also in **Places**.
The Trash icon can also be found in any Nautilus Window one the right hand tree menu at the bottom of the **Computer** section.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I found the trash folder by revealing hidden files. It is not the same as the Unity trash, when I use unity the trash contains what I trashed in Unity, and Gnome has what I trashed in Gnome. But there is no icon in "Places" nor at bottom of "Computer" section in my setup. I dragged and dropped the trash file on to the desktop as you seem to suggest, but something isn't right with that solution. When I delete something now, a new trash folder is re-created in the old location, and deleted items go there rather than to the desktop trash.

Comment: I did not mean to drag the trash itself to another location, you can drag the deleted files themselves to another location if you did not want to restore then to the folder from which they were deleted.  As far as the link to the trash folder, it should be in any Nautilus window in the left hand pane(called the tree), Nautilus should be the same in Gnome and Unity as it is a Gnome program

Comment: Ah, I have now found it, but it is not visible in tree view, only places, but that is good enough for now. So I have found the Answer to my query with your help, show hidden files and /or select "places" sidebar view. I think it ought to be visible in tree view as well, so could I submit this as a bug or mark for attention in some way?

Comment: It's not a bug, more of a feature request, so I would not submit it as a bug, it would be fluff to clutter the bug site.  It could be submitted as a feature request but I'm not sure where. I would think it is related to Gnome as Nautilus must work differently in Gnome than in Unity, but I could not find any links on gnome.org to refer you to.....